# Are questions about romantic relationships on topic?

Tags: discussion

We've had a few questions about romantic relationships here.

Previously there was a site here dedicated to relationships - unfortunately, it was closed.

Do we want to allow questions about romantic relationships here?

Comment: I've always considered this site a broader implementation of the closed proposal, meaning that IMHO it *really should* be part of the site's scope.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Let's at least give it a shot

I see no reason not to. Romantic relationships are indeed a type of interpersonal skill, and if they remain appropriate for the site I see no reason not have allow them. What would disallowing them mean? By allowing them we're allowing the users of another failed site the ability to continue asking questions that they were unable too. Often broadening a topic often helps a site succeed, and if we encompass romantic relationships into this site, I think it can really help it succeed.

I think we should allow it, even if it's just for the beta to just get a rough idea what they sort of question would be like and what quantities they would be asked in, if they turn out to become a large part of the site, we may have to keep them if we want the site to become fully operational.

Comment: I don't like the start of the answer (for a start there's no pun at the top :P) but also there are quite a few reasons not to!

Comment: @Tim I can see why there are reasons not too but we should at least give them a try, if they turn out to be too difficult to manage then we can always dissalow them in the future, but this is what beta is for! We need to find what works and what doesn't work :P

Comment: Okay, sure let's give it a shot, but also keep an open mind (and perhaps come back to this discussion at the end of the private beta).

Comment: Also for a pun - how about **Let's give it a shot** (if you don't think punnage is needed here that's fine)

Comment: I'm accepting this today - and I expect it will stay accepted. When we get to the end of this beta I expect I'll ask this question again.

Answer (score 3):

Romantic relationships are a "subset" of interpersonal relationships. As such they are on topic on a site like this. Some percentage, perhaps 10 per cent, of questions may be about romantic issues.

Yes, some SE members have bad memories of a failed dating site. That may have been because the topic was too narrow, and drew questions that became progressively more "granular" and graphic, and attracted a narrower and narrower audience.

As long as we avoid that on this site, we should be fine.

Answer (score -12):

#### No, let's keep it platonic, thanks

I've got a few reasons for thinking that relationships should be off topic:

1. They're very subjective and it's quite hard to mark a very similar question as a duplicate because of one small detail which differs.
2. They're very, very complicated for the OP to explain fully and often need a lot of back and forth in the comments to get all those details.
3. Answers are quite subjective - what works for one couple is terrible for another. (This can contribute to the difficulty marking duplicates).  This means each answer effectivley consists of a list of options.

---

<sup>I'm sad this got so many downvotes despite my excellent pun...</sup>

Comment: I don't see why the first point is a problem.

Comment: @TGar We'd have lots of very similar questions with very similar answers - causing information to be duplicated and repeated (a little like "Get a lawyer" on [workplace.se]). This leads to a very poor answer rate as well (for example all of the "my computer boots to a black screen" questions on [ubuntu.se])

Comment: Isn't it a matter of setting? Duplicate doesn't necessarily mean "exactly the same". If we'll get used to closing more than less, I don't think it's actual problem. But I am aware that now I am questioning the point itself, not its relevance.

Comment: How do any of these points apply to questions about romantic relationships more than to *any other questions* on this site?

Comment: @Randal'Thor they quite possibly dont, this was my opinion, not me certainly being right. as said aboce, we’ll review this at the end of public beta (and hopefully they will be fine)

Comment: @Tim, `They're very, very complicated for the OP to explain fully and often need a lot of back and forth in the comments to get all those details.` in this case, I agree, but the community can vote, comment and try to set the question as on-topic, otherwise, I probablu downvote and VTC "vote to close" a too broad question.